# Updating a postmodern row in a more functional way

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp

I have a couple of classes (namely `book` and `user`). I need to update a `book` by setting its `lended` slot to `t` and its `lended-to` to the borrower's `id`.

I'm using Postmodern as a back-end to a PostgreSQL database

This is what I came up with (I hope the names are self-describing enough)

```
(defmethod lend-book ((to-lend book) borrower) ;borrower is a user instance
  (if (book-lent to-lend)
      nil
      (let (to-lend (get-dao 'book (book-id to-lend)))
        (setf (book-lent-to to-lend) (user-id borrower))
        (setf (book-lent to-lend) t)
        (update-dao to-lend))))
```

But it seems too much imperative to me.

Is there a more functional way to do this or does Postmodern get in the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying state, so that's what you write.  I see this as idiomatic.

I just see two problems with your code:

1. Your `defmethod` has its lambda list mixed up:  it should be `(to-lend book)`, not the other way around.  This should give some warnings or errors.
2. The participle of "lend" is "lent", so the slots should be named `book-lent` and `book-lent-to`.