# Can I apply functional programming concepts when manipulating databases?

Tags: javascript, database, functional-programming

I am very interested in functional programming and have recently begun delving deeper into it and trying to apply the concepts in my projects. But I think I've hit some sort of brick wall with databases since they seem to go against the entire idea of functional programming.

For example, a user can have an array of user IDs that show who is friends with them, if I delete the user I want to delete all references to that user in the friends arrays. That sounds like something I could use array.filter() for (in javascript) but that returns a new array and would leave the original array untouched (as a pure function should), so I can't actually change the database using these types of functions.

So does functional programming just not fit in with databases and I should try applying it in different aspects of my project or is there something I'm missing.

Comment: Somehow related: a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723173/updating-a-postmodern-row-in-a-more-functional-way) I asked years ago about doing database stuff in a more functional style.

Comment: If you're thinking about doing database differently, you might want [rethinkdb](https://www.rethinkdb.com/) ^_^

Comment: [db-engines.com](https://db-engines.com/en/) is a good resource for comparing various products to find one that matches your needs

Answer (score 0):

[Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) is one way. You treat the core table(s) as immutable; they're just sequences of events. The current state of the system can be determined by replaying the events in order.

This provides an audit log and allows "time travel." ([Redux](https://redux.js.org/) works on a similar concept.)